# Hint for @NonNull not working by pressing ALT+ENTER

Tags: android-studio, annotations, keyboard-shortcuts, nullable, android-studio-3.3

I am getting problem in shortcut of Auto Insert code: <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

> Not annotated parameter overrides @ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
>
> **Inspection info:** This inspection reports
>   problems related to @Nullable and @NotNull annotations usage
>   configured in Constant conditions & exceptions inspection.

I know that by pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> we are getting option as below:

[image]

And It will annotate automatically by press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

But I am getting following options (There is no option to annotate directly)

[image]

Why the above image not showing option to `Annotate` directly.

I am using Android Studio:

```
Android Studio 3.3.2
Build #AI-182.5107.16.33.5314842, built on February 16, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 4.18.0-16-generic
```

## Issue:

I have one project in PC-1 named "UserApp" created using Android Studio 3.3.1,
Another Project "DriverApp" in PC-2 created using same version.

This annotation problems come up with both project but In "UserApp" its solved by updating **Android Studio 3.3.2**

**Now I am coping "DriverApp" in PC-1 but and compiling in Android Studio 3.3.2 but getting same error as previously I got.**

**How can I rebuild "DriverApp" project so I get that annotation working?**

I have tried:

- Restart, Invalidate cache, and Restart
- Build Project
- Clean Project

Comment: When I tried to add annotation in Android studio 3.4 , it automatically added dependency `implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'` . So try adding this dependency and check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer as I have implemented following steps:

- After pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>, Click on right arrow of **"Inspection '@NotNull/@Nullable problems'"** and then `Run inspection on...`

You will be prompted for Scope of Inspection. That should be `Whole Project`.

[image]

In that you will came to know how many places need to change. By clicking on "AndroidX Annotation", It will use annotation for AndroidX.

This problem occurred after Migration of **AndroidX.**

Hope it will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Annotation Processors. Tick 'Enable annotation processing'.[image]

Comment: File | Other Settings | Default Settings, navigate to the compiler settings, annotation processing and enable this option before importing the project.'     In android studio 3.3 there's change in schema you can find it here and it works in new projects only after change done,its working in my current project also

Comment: In that I am just getting option for `SDK Location` only.

Comment: In default setting u need to go in settings for new projects

Comment: I have updated my question to get more understandable.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts richa, I got solution as I answered.